# Crystal Reports - group total at begining of group

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I have this report:

```
Question Group 
----Question - [TOTAL]
--------Answer 1 (10)
--------Answer 2 (0)
--------Answer 3 (8)
--------Answer 4 (2)
----Total: 20
```

**Total: 20** is calculated with running total field, and it can only be calculated after each question finishes. 
What I want is to place this value at the beginning ([TOTAL]), so it can be used to calculate percentages (--------Answer 1 (50%)).

I tried with formulas, with no success.

Comment: Can you use a summary instead of a Running Total?

Comment: I guess I could. But the problem is different... I need the total above, before the group starts. Running fields or summaries calculate after each group ends...

Comment: A Running Total would only work in the footer but general summaries work anywhere.

Comment: You're right Ryan, sorry. However, the result is not ok.. summary is counting values I do not want to. It's possible to ignore records with a specific condition (ex: var1=0)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the SQL that feeds the report and then used a formula to do what I want

```
count({newfield},{group})
```